# Reliable way to identify the caller

Tags: solidity

Is a reliable way to identify the caller with the following code?

```
bool isContract = msg.sender != tx.origin;
```

Comment: Please don't exclude contracts from interacting with your contract. If it's to avoid some security vulnerability, it's probably ineffective, and it means that no one using a multisig wallet can use your contract. `tx.origin` may also stop working in future Ethereum versions, especially as account abstraction work comes in.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Also you can check the size of the code in the address if it is bigger than zero, is a contract

```
function isContract(address addr) returns (bool) {
  uint size;
  assembly { size := extcodesize(addr) }
  return size > 0;
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Note that during execution of a contract's constructor, that address's code size will be 0.